# Ng-nestable angular buttons for expand and collapse

Tags: angularjs, jquery-plugins, angularjs-directive

Can someone let me know how to create button for collapse all/expand all to jquery nestable but in angularjs version? 
https://github.com/kamilkp/ng-nestable

I'm able to do it when it start: $nestable.collapseAllOnStart = false; but i also want to have two buttons to collapse all/expand all.

Is it even possible? 
Edit: For now i'm using jquery way:

```
<menu id="nestable-menu">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-wide btn-o btn-info" data-action="expand-all" translate="licences.expandAll">Expand All</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-wide btn-o btn-warning" data-action="collapse-all" translate="licences.collapseAll">Collapse All</button>
</menu>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div ng-nestable ng-model="departmentsTest" clas="dd">
            {{$item.text}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And script in html page:

```
<script>
$('#nestable-menu').on('click', function(e)
    {
        var target = $(e.target),
            action = target.data('action');
        if (action === 'expand-all') {
            $('.dd').nestable('expandAll');
        }
        if (action === 'collapse-all') {
            $('.dd').nestable('collapseAll');
        }
    });
```

But to be honest i would like to use angular for this.

Comment: I have the exact same problem right now. Also, could you give me details about your `$nestable.collapseAllOnStart = false;` ? I can't seem to find a `$nestable` service

Comment: Sorry but it was so long time ago that I did not remember it, and do not have access to this project which use it.

Comment: The Angular-Nestable library is rather old, first and last commits date from 2 years. I ended up crafting a little nested list-groups model for my use-case. Thanks anyway for answering